# Can't Find Response Headers in an NodeJS - ExpressJS App

Tags: node.js, express, server, http-headers, response-headers

I have set up a simple api request using node/express.js to access the Feedly Dev Api:  https://developer.feedly.com/.  The Feedly Api comes with two response headers -- `X-Ratelimit-Count` and `X-Ratelimit-Reset`.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to access.

Here is the relevant parts of my express.js file:

```
app.get('/feedly', async (request, response) => {
  const apiUrl =
    'https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user/[USER_ID]/category/global.all'

  const fetchResponse = await fetch(apiUrl, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.FEEDLY_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
    }
  })
  const json = await fetchResponse.json()
  response.json(json)
  response.end()
})
```

what do I have to do in order to see both X-Ratelimit-Count and X-Ratelimit-Reset response headers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch API: [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers)

```js
(async() => {
  const fetchResponse = await fetch("https://httpbin.org/anything");
  
  console.log(fetchResponse.headers.get('X-Ratelimit-Count'))
  console.log(fetchResponse.headers.get('X-Ratelimit-Reset'))
  
  fetchResponse.headers.forEach((v, k) => console.log(`${k}: ${v}`));
})();
```

Comment: Thanks -- that is exactly what I needed to know.